# Алгоритм сортировки которая делает наименьшее количество перестановок

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Алгоритм сортировки которая делает наименьшее количество перестановок. 
Есть ли такой алгоритм и как реализовать его и вывести количество перестановок.Помогите плиз ? Не знаю такого алгоритма.

Comment: что имеется ввиду под перестановками ? обмены не равных элементов ?

Comment: на отсортированной коллекции любой алгоритм сделает 0 перестановок

Comment: @Grundy не любой а только устойчивый алгоритм - так как если в отсортированной последовательности некоторые элементы равны в неустойчивом алгоритме они обменяются местами

Comment: @ampawd, разве?

Comment: конечно такой алгоритм есть) делаем сортировку любым способом через указатели) потом делаем вытягивание самих элементов используя не более N-1 операций обмена.

Comment: мне даётся массив например 3 2 1 и мне я хочу последовательно пометить их . и мне здесь прийдётся 3 раза помечать.

Comment: @futuretourist вообще-то 1 хватит...

Comment: мне нужно последовательно помечать

Comment: сначала 1 затем 2 затем 3

Comment: 1 3 2 5 4 сначала 1 2 ,затем 3 4 ,затем 5. 3 раза

Comment: @pavel как можно это реализовать ?

Comment: @Grundy смотри мой измененный коментарий

Comment: @ampawd как мне быть в такой ситуации ?

Comment: @futuretourist: О чем речь вообще? Что такое "пометить" и откуда какое-то "помечание" вообще взялось в этой задаче?

Answer (score 5):

Если речь идет об разнообразных алгоритмах обменных in-place сортировок, то минимальное количество *перестановок пар* (*обменов*) элементов достигается на обыкновенной классической *[Сортировке Выбором](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC)*. Она сразу перемещает очередной элемент в его финальную позицию, т.е. делает не более N-1 обменов.

Если же требуется минимизировать количество *модификаций* элементов исходного массива (записей в исходный массив), то эта величина минимизируется *[Циклической Сортировкой](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_sort)*, которая просто в лоб вычисляет финальную позицию каждого элемента массива (путем подсчета количества меньших элементов) и сразу переносит элемент в его финальное положение ("вытесняя" оттуда хранящийся там элемент), после чего выполняет ту же операцию для вытесненного элемента и т.д. тем самым выполняя обход цикла перестановки до возврата в начало цикла. Обойдя все циклы, вы полностью отсортируете массив, выполнив не более N записей в него.

Comment: Но если **только** первый элемент не на своем месте, то будет сделано n-1 перестановок. Тут нужна модификация, которая найдет максимальный упорядоченный набор и досортирует к нему остальные элементы.

Comment: @mega: Как может быть не на своем месте только один элемент??? Это невозможно. Напоминаю, что я веду речь о классических in-place сортировках.

Comment: Не, in-place тут ни при чем, отсортируйте вставками массив 5,1,2,3,4. Вы тут переставите все элементы, хотя достаточно только один. Это классическая проблема.

Comment: @mega: Это как это вы предлагаете отсортировать массив { 5,1,2,3,4 }, переставив только один элемент???

Comment: ну вот так - 5 поставить в конец, удивил? )

Comment: @mega: Ну здрасьте! Задача in-place сортировки массива - это не задача из области "переложите одну спичку, чтобы из слова 'дуся' получилось слово 'попа'". В данном случае невозможно "поставить 5 в конец". Считайте, что массив закончился на 4 и там больше нет места, чтобы туда что-то ставить.

Comment: Я не предлагаю туда что-то ставить - только сдвинуть массив, если конечно Вы понимаете, что это не одно и то же, что переставить все элементы.

Comment: @mega: "Сдвинуть массив" - это *одно и то же*, что переставить все элементы. Это само собой разумеется. Вам, разумеется, никто не запрещает ввести в рассмотрение платформу, на которой существует операция "сдвига массива" с какой-то своей "стоимостью" и рассматривать задачу в рамках этой платформы. Но, в первых, это уже совсем другая история. И, во-вторых, в исходном вопросе такой платформы не вводилось.

Answer (score 3):

Совершенно некорректно поставленный вопрос, просто потому, что вы спрашиваете *только* о перестановках. Тогда годится, например, немного модифицированный алгоритм сортировки выбором - он будет работать медленно, но перестановок будет ровно столько, сколько надо, чтоб поставить все элементы на свои места.

Например, находим позиции элементов в отсортированной последовательности, ничего не переставляя - скажем, выделив для этого еще один массив, а затем сразу ставим каждый элемент на свое место, при возможности обменивая с тем, который при этом тоже станет на свое место. Вы же ничего не спрашиваете о том, каковы допустимые затраты на дополнительную память или количество сравнений?

Формально алгоритм выбором выполняет перестановок точно не больше, чем общее количество элементов, но при этом его время работы - O(N<sup>2</sup>).

Или вас реально интересует именно количество перестановок?

Answer (score 2):

вобще многое зависит от того что сортируется, если числа то существует [сортировка подсчётом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC)

она вобще ни одного обмена не делает, и в лучшем случае работает за линейное время.

Comment: в худшем тоже) Только вот линейно не от числа элементов, а от размера "корзины".

Comment: @pavel сложность тут ещё и от реализации этого алгоритма зависит

Comment: Каким образом вы предлагаете применять этот алгоритм в общем случае, если элементы исходного массива - не числа?

Comment: @AnT я такое не предлагал вобще то )) но вопрос этот конечно интересный